# Groovy - How do I use metaprogramming to add tracing to all static methods of a class?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

This is what I have so far:

```
static def traceMethods(Class clazz) {
    def mc = clazz.metaClass

    mc.static.invokeMethod = { String name, args ->
        List types = args.collect { it == null ? null : it.getClass() }
        MetaMethod metmeth = mc.getStaticMetaMethod(name, *types) //throws exception sometimes when it shouldnt

        println "Starting method $name"
        def result = metmeth.doMethodInvoke(delegate, args)         
        println "Finished method $name"

        return result
    }
}
```

This works perfectly most of the time.  However, sometimes the call to `getStaticMetaMethod` throws an exception when it shouldn't.

EDIT: The exception it throws is:

```
 groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.HandleMetaClass#getStaticMetaMethod.|Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [class java.lang.String, null] due to overlapping prototypes between:|?[class java.lang.String, class [Ljava.lang.Object;]|?[class java.lang.String, class [Ljava.lang.Class;]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMostSpecificParams(MetaClassImpl.java:2906)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethodInternal(MetaClassImpl.java:2859)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:2800)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getMethodWithCachingInternal(MetaClassImpl.java:1181)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createPogoCallSite(MetaClassImpl.java:3022)
```

Comment: @lgs - I edited my question to include the exception

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to do the following instead?

```
MetaMethod metmeth = mc.getStaticMetaMethod(name, types as Class[])
```

Let's say args was `[1,"abc",true]`. That would result in `types` being `[Integer,String,Boolean]`.

Using the spread operator (`*`) here causes Groovy to attempt to calls a method with a signature like `getStaticMetaMethod(String,Integer,String,Boolean)`. That's probably not what you intended.

However, since there is no method of that signature, Groovy falls back to trying to cast `*type` into an appropriate collection-like object. In this case, it has the option of `Class[]` or `Object[]`, since the methods `getStaticMetaMethod(String,Class[])` and `getStaticMetaMethod(String,Object[])` both exist.

When args contains only a null value, Groovy can't decide between casting to `Class[]` or `Object[]`, and hence the exception. Using an explicit cast (`types as Class[]`) makes your intention clear to Groovy and removes the ambiguity.

By the way, you can reproduce the exception with your original code and:

```
class A {
    static def doX(String s) { }
}
traceMethods(A)
A.doX(null)
```